# Question popped up under me

Tags: support, user-accounts

This question here popped just recently under me and i do not remember asking it at all never even got notifications of answers 
[WordPress Admin Bar Moving Links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12502/wordpress-admin-bar-moving-links)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? I'm not clear what *"popped up under me"* means in the context of this site.

Comment: it just showed up under the main page so i clicked it and my name is the asker  but the rep and stuff is low or non existent. I have made my own mods to my admin bar and not asked this question at all. So i am just a little confused. as well it never even gave me inbox messages that people have answered it show i was not sure if it was a bug or not. in my profile it shows the questions i have asked and that is not in there at all

Comment: Even when you click on the profile it takes it to someone else. my username is xLRDxREVENGEx not Tyler Yates but that is my profile image

Comment: Oh and my name is Tyler Yates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked by an unregistered user, so it could be someone that shares a PC with you.

We do store the contents of the unregistered user fields (that is, name, email, and url) in a cookie so if you asked a question, didn't clear cookies, didn't log out -- someone else could ask and have those fields pre-filled as you based on the browser cookie.

Answer (score 2):

That question is attributed to [profile with *unregistered* status](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4059/tyler-yates) so someone must have used your details for authentication when creating that question. IPs check shows that access was made from one of two IPs that you use (less common).

Are you sharing your computer/browser with someone who might have asked that question?

Comment: I am the only one who knows how to use this site my roomies are dumb when it comes to coding. I do have a dynamic ip on my internet and go back and forth with laptop and desktop but they share the same internet

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx well, either someone intentionally identified as you or by mistake (hitting browser form-fill feature, etc). Or you have gaping hole in your memories. :)

Comment: Who knows. I just saw that and was like i asked that question and then my name but then it clicked that i dont use the username listed on that question never have. Unless a friend of my posted it ill have to call him.